# Making versions match in angular 2

Tags: angular, versions, primeng

I'm using the angular 2 quickstart application from Angular.io: https://github.com/angular/quickstart

And I'm trying to make some basic additions to it. Specifically I would like to use the PrimeNG module to display data using a DataTable component: http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

To do this, I add "primeng": "1.0.0-beta.17" to package.json under dependencies, which now looks as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",

"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.4",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"systemjs": "0.19.24",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "^0.6.25",

"primeng": "1.0.0-beta.17"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^3.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.2",
"typescript": "^2.0.3",
"typings": "^1.4.0",

"canonical-path": "0.0.2",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"tslint": "^3.15.1",
"lodash": "^4.16.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^3.3.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4"
```

},

Running npm install now causes a version conflict during the typings install stage:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid  The package reflect-metadata does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!

npm ERR! peerinvalid  Peer angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.7 wants reflect-metadata@~0.1.8

npm ERR! peerinvalid  Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.12 wants reflect-metadata@0.1.2
```

General question: this is just one example of a problem I encounter regularly while trying to get angular 2 to work. What is the **best practice** for avoiding and resolving version conflicts like these? I have tried manually updating the versions until everything fits, but this is like playing a game of whack-a-mole where each conflict I deal with causes 3 others to pop up. Is there some systematic way to go about it?

Specific question: why does npm mention "angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.7" and "angular2@2.0.0-beta.12" when I have different versions of these specified in package.json? I could understand if one of them was somehow internally referenced by primeng, but not both when they raise this versioning conflict.

update: deleting the node_modules and typings directories in my project directory and running "npm install" again made this conflict disappear. However, I am still interested in hearing about best practices and explanations for this problem.

I'm very new to angular 2 so please do not hesitate to elaborate on any answers you may give.

Comment: That's a very good question.  I recently was tasked with enhancing some early Angular2 code, including adding some basic pagination to the tables in the application.  After trying angular2-datatable, ngx-pagination, angular2 material, and a couple of others I can't remember, I'm ready to throw my hands up, use jQuery, and call it done.